angular-auth-oidc-client with Facebook
I've configured the angular-auth-oidc-client@19.0.0 for facebook with respondType='code' and logLevel: LogLevel.Debug.
After signing in a facebook user, my app (angular 19) got the following callback URL with the code:
https://localhost:4444/home?code=AQDK26vcYPSRc4uXbPjKjTtsA5ctPcBRcNxHj90LNciMKadtKQlC5WYCdepvAk5Gz-L6acarWbpk04t2-9HcllEKfyLoL1gwPQ-N383BMTwbfz8BI68TV9yPKsqHSS42N-PZhdTwywnUZ9D95z9K6rgDoSG20XklvdwGXK71NCyoBYoSbKzvoQCGh0rSb_hOajRNxflXbCn4Pl9uSDbSSM-lPTJUkfwn5yuOOIuZJrgzbKKo6xc6fg8gwc6ZVgWZytiELiJG-m8SZUuc2gWaanEqvSLE0Crwm_t474sKHQtfQNRKaN99D2KALnPus1smnHuoHDF9otiisMpuqvh46lrHod6F7d9LhuR2Bk9ujFBsy736WKNsUZVTuMMmBQLLda9SLGYs-CTkS2mt6b6vAnHdTZBIuDVnybLO3_nMtznrDg0AUpVW4pND5DXQI2dglofUSi6J4-QZxM5O1oAvzG7Vo7xTfywJpgNzVNIRuU-mQ&state=d2f6b3a9d8c4288dc9adea6a56639061b8JzHjT0l#=_
But the angular-auth-oidc-client seemed to not consume the query parameters in the callback, not redirect to the configured redirectUrl, and also did not output any error.
I should also mention that my angular-auth-oidc-client already worked for other 2 configs "cognito" and "google" so that I believe I had a proper OidcSecurityService.checkAuthMultiple in my code.
I could not find any mentioning in the Internet that the angular-auth-oidc-client works for facebook. Did anybody already successfully configure angular-auth-oidc-client for facebook?
